# I am not able to edit post URL

Tags: url, edit, permalinks, slug

After writing a new article when I am going to edit the URl name it is not happening and taking a RL name by default. I'm using wordpress and Rank Math Plugin. I've tried all possible changes like setting the permalink as post or custom but it is not rectified yet. Please someone give advice.

I've tried all possible changes like setting the permalink as post or custom but it is not rectified yet. I want someone to give solution for editing my slug or post URL.